# Python: index 3D array with 3D bool and return 3D array of same size... elegantly

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, 3d

I have a 3D image scan (shape: `335x306x306`, total elements: `31368060`) and I want to mask it with a 3D boolean mask of the same size to return a masked image of the same size.

When I simply index the array with the mask as so:

```
masked_image = image_pix[mask]
```

I get a 1D array of the image pixel values where the mask is = 1 ordered by standard row-major (C-style) order (as explained [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html)). It only has 6953600 elements because of the masking.

So how do I reshape this 1D array back into the 3D array if I don't have the indices? I realize that I can use the indices of the mask itself to iteratively populate a 3D array with the masked values, but I am hoping there is a more elegant (and computationally efficient) solution that doesn't rely on for loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just thought about this for a little while longer and realized that I can accomplish this by logical indexing.

```
masked_image = image_pix # define the masked image as the full image
masked_image[mask==0] = 0 # define the pixels where mask == 0 as 0
```

That was easy...

Comment: If you need your `image_pix` unmodified you should do a copy: `masked_image = image_pix.copy()`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`np.ma.MaskedArray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.baseclass.html#numpy.ma.MaskedArray):

```
marr = np.ma.array(image_pix, mask=mask)
```

The "normal" indexing with `[mask]` removes all masked values so there is no garantuee that it can be reshaped into 3D again (because it lost items) so that's not possible.

---

However `MaskedArray`s keep their shape:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> arr = np.random.randint(0, 10, 16).reshape(4, 4)

>>> marr = np.ma.array(arr, mask=arr>6)

>>> marr.shape
(4, 4)

>>> marr
masked_array(data =
 [[3 -- 0 1]
 [4 -- 6 --]
 [2 -- 6 0]
 [4 5 0 0]],
             mask =
 [[False  True False False]
 [False  True False  True]
 [False  True False False]
 [False False False False]],
       fill_value = 999999)
```